# Does it make sense to use statistical tests on measures of model fits obtained for individual participants?

Tags: modeling, model-comparison

I have a dataset from an experiment in which a sample of participants repeatedly done a variation of visual search task (for each participant there is about 400 trials) in two conditions. The predictions for this experiments suggest a comparison between two non-linear models that have the same number of parameters and are non-nested, with one model hypothetically better at predicting results in one condition and the other model better at predicting the other condition. I can fit the models to the data (with MLE) and obtain BIC scores. Using the difference in BIC scores, I can show that the prediction is correct.

Now, I want to show that this prediction also holds for analyses based on individual participants' data. I thought of two ways of doing this:

1) Fit the model to each subject data, choose best model, make a 2x2 table "best model" x condition, use $\chi^2$ test or a Fisher's test to see whether the distribution of best models differ between conditions.

2) Fit the model to each subject data, obtain a measure of fit (BIC?) and use it as dependent variable with traditional tests (e.g., t-test or Wilcoxon test).

While the first option makes sense to me, I'm having some doubts about the second one, because model fits measures are data-dependent. Accordingly, comparison between fits of different participants does not make sense. On the other hand, because two models are fitted to each condition within each subjects, the difference between the fits should be comparable between participants. So is it viable to use the second approach? Are there better alternatives?